# calling another optional method at the end of a static method

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, forwarding

I wrote a method like this:

```
Redirect::to('www.foo.com');
```

The content of this method is as follows:

```
public static function to($url) {
    header("Location: $url"); exit();
}
```

Also, i want to use this method as follows:

```
Redirect::to('www.foo.com')->withData(['some' => 'data']);
```

Before forwarding, I want to save some data to the session with "withData" method. 
How can I implement this? Which design template should I use?

Comment: Well, you can't chain it because the redirect has already happened. Why not just pass that data as a second argument?

Comment: you are right. the first solution that comes to mind is to adding as parameter. 
i wonder, is it possible in php?

Comment: Is what possible? Adding another parameter to the function?